# get host by name C++ is not showing the updated IP adress

Tags: c++, gethostbyname

I am trying to set a dynamic DNS for my phone and I have created a hostname on no-ip.com with the name: sdfgcs.ddns.net. When I use the online tools to resolve the IP, I get the correct ans: 111.65.61.78. However, if I use the nslookup or gethostbyname function, it shows

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   sdfgcs.ddns.net
Address: 111.65.38.226
```

which is the original ip address when the ddns is set. It seems that the gethostbyname function is not able to get the update IP address. Can someone please suggest what may be the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The behavior of `gethostbyname` depends on `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/host.conf`, and then possibly further on `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf`. Consider `strace`-ing your program to see how your particular system (and libc) implements name resolution. Also note that `gethostbyname` is deprecated in favor of `getaddrinfo()` and friends.